# hover on one div to card flip image another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a link in one div and when I hover mouse on it I need to get card flip in another div.
Basicaly I just want to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/
when I hover another div.

```
$(".flip").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok... so do that... Where is the question?

Comment: Can you post some HTML?

Comment: @Neal The demo he shows flips the card when you hover over that card. Omadawn is asking how to flip the card when you hover over a certain different part of the page.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/YHeKX/34/ ?

Comment: Working: http://jsfiddle.net/YHeKX/36/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to change the selector, `$(".flip")`, to the other div's id, `$("#flipit")` in my case, and change `$(this)` to `$(document)` or `$('body')`. To prevent it from flipping all cards, add an ID to the one you want to flip

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/YHeKX/35/)

```
$("#flipit").hover(function(){
  $(document).find("#specificCard").toggleClass("flipped");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This will flip all cards on the page